# How do I call a method in Scala through javascript & ajax?

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework-2.0, action, ajax-request

I do not know if my title was perhaps a little misleading. But here's what I really need help with.

I'm making a get on this url:

```
$.get("/fb/login/"+fbEmail, function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

This is my routes:

```
GET /fb/login/:email  presentation.controllers.Auth.authenticateSocialNetwork(email:String)
```

And here's my action:

```
def authenticateSocialNetwork(email:String) = Action {
   if(!editorRepo.getEditorByEmail(email).isEmpty){
      Redirect(routes.Profile.editorProfile).withSession(Security.username -> email)
   } else {
      Redirect(routes.Profile.initiatorProfile).withSession(Security.username -> email)
   }
}
```

My expectation from this is that my action gets **called** and fires of what's inside it. In other words, **Redirecting**.

But what actually happens, which is not so illogical, is that my $.get call gets a response with my redirect's.

How do I actually **call** my action-method, without sending a response to javascript?

---

Here's my function in javascript, posting this snippet for it to be more clear in our discussion in the comments above.

```
function addClickToLoginButtons(){
$("#loginWithFb").click(function(){
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse){
            FB.api('/me', function(response){
                var fbEmail = response.email;
                $.get("/fb/isRegisteredAtNetwork/"+fbEmail+"/facebook", function(data){
                    if(data == "true"){
                        if(confirm("Do you want to log with facebook-account "+fbEmail+"?")){
                                $.get("/fb/login/"+fbEmail, function(data){  *//HERE'S WHERE I WOULD WANT TO CALL MY METHOD IN SCALA*
                                    console.log(data);
                                });
                        } else {
                            console.log("try again with a different facebook-account");
                        } //end confirm else
                    } else {
                        console.log("Logged in not in database");
                    }//end get else
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log("permission not granted");
        } // end authResponse else
    }, {scope: 'email'});
});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well what you're trying to do. Please correct me if I'm wrong: You want to, let's say, click a button that will trigger the ajax code and once the ajax get executed, you want to be redirected to a given page?
If that's not the case, could you explain in a bit more detail what you want to do?
If that's the case, why not just use a simple Http call?

Comment: You're correct, that's exactly what I want to do. I have thought about  a http call but since I'm passing a session variable with my Security-trait I can't do so. I need to reach my security-trait.

Comment: In both cases (http or ajax), you'll end up executing `authenticateSocialNetwork`, I don't really see how an http request would prevent you from using your trait variables.
Do you get any errors when using a http request with this? If so, what are the errors?

Comment: Right now with ajax, when `authenticateSocialNetwork` gets executed it sends a response to ajax. This response includes my redirected page, but it doesnt actually redirect. This is my problem. I dont want to send a respons, I want to execute whats inside my `authenticateSocialNetwork`. When you say http call, do you mean from the javascript file or in the `authenticateSocialNetwork` method? If I redirect from my javascript file I wont be able to use my trait? I might be a little confused :)

Comment: No I mean from the client side, for example in html you would create your button as: `<a href="http://example.com/fb/login/dummy@dummy.com">Click here</a>` Once this button clicked, the action `authenticateSocialNetwork` is called and is passed the appropriate email, this will then redirect your user... In ajax, I don't think that's actually possible, since it's gonna wait for the response from the server and in your case it's a redirect response.

Comment: I posted my function in another answer below. So you see more clearly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your action, instead of returning Redirect, return `Ok(urlToBeRedirectedTo).withSession(...)`. Once this response received in the javascript code, do your stuff and then call `window.location = urlToBeRedirectedTo;`.

This will add the email to the session, and will redirect to the wanted URL.

Comment: Got it!
That got it to work just like I want to. 
Thank you for helping me thinking outside the box, sometimes things goes a little fast. Session variables will of course be there on the next page when I'm defining it in my method. Thanks to you @about.blank