# Is there a way to check an email ID and a value next to it in database from frontend without submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, scala

I have a registration form and I would like to check if the email is already in database (PSQL) without submitting the form. Vanilla javascript or jQuery only please. No PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a blur event on your email input field
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp

When it will be called (user clicked out of email input field) make AJAX call to API which will check if email exists and return feedback that you can then present to user via notification. All that can be done without any submitting of form, but you need PHP for API or something similar on the server side.

About AJAX calls:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The backend is built with Scala, do I have to ask my backend dev to build the API?

Comment: I am not familiar with Scala, but apparently you can call a Scala method through jquery and ajax so yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612825/how-do-i-call-a-method-in-scala-through-javascript-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to submit the form, You can build an API on Your server to tell you if a certain email is already in the system. Then from the front end you request this API to check whether this email is already registered or not.

Obviously on your server once the form is submitted, you need to check again for that, because front-end validations are meant just to make the experience more smooth, and everything important should also be validated on the back end.